# How to generate javascript code with javascript if posible

Tags: javascript

Im quite new at javascript so dont expect me to know much else than whats written :)

So i have a javascript file with a lot of javascript codes that almost looks the same except a number is changing with each element.

Most of my code are inside a function just not written since it's a cut out.

**The relevant part of my code looks something like:**

```
    //Upgrade 1
    if (CREDITS >= UpgradePrice1 && Upgrade1 === 0){
        document.getElementById("Upgrade1").style.display = "block";}
    else{document.getElementById("Upgrade1").style.display = "none";}

    //Upgrade 2
    if (CREDITS >= UpgradePrice2 && Upgrade2 === 0){
        document.getElementById("Upgrade2").style.display = "block";}
    else{document.getElementById("Upgrade2").style.display = "none";}

    //Upgrade 3
    if (CREDITS >= UpgradePrice3 && Upgrade3 === 0){
        document.getElementById("Upgrade3").style.display = "block";}
    else{document.getElementById("Upgrade3").style.display = "none";

    And so on...
```

The values are assigned in a file named StandardValues.js:

```
var UpgradeName1 = "Craftmanship Lvl 1";
var UpgradePrice1 = 100;
var UpgradeContent1 = "+100% Gods Hands! <br> +20% Blessed Farmer!";
var Upgrade1 = 0;

var UpgradeName2 = "Craftmanship Lvl 2";
var UpgradePrice2 = 200;
var UpgradeContent2 = "+100% Gods Hands! <br> +20% Blessed Farmer!";
var Upgrade2 = 0;

And so on...
```

If it were a html code i tried to generate i would use a php while function and make it echo the same code with the changed number a specefic amount of times.
But since this is inside a javascript file i really dont think thats an option?

The javascript code from before is in a .js file.

**I think a potential fix could be:**

```
Inside a .php file:

<?php
$Upgrades = 10;
$CurrentUpgrade = 1;

while ($Upgrades >= $CurrentUpgrade){
echo "
<script>
function Upgrade1(){
//Upgrade ".$CurrentUpgrade."
    if (CREDITS >= UpgradePrice".$CurrentUpgrade." && Upgrade".$CurrentUpgrade." === 0){
        document.getElementById('Upgrade".$CurrentUpgrade."').style.display = 'block';}
    else{document.getElementById('Upgrade".$CurrentUpgrade."').style.display = 'none';}
}
</script>
";
$CurrentUpgrade ++;

}

?>
```

*Sry for any typo in this part, made it quite quick.

But i would quite like to keep the javascript code inside my .js file instead of having it in my .php file.

**So to sum it up i would like to (If possible):**

- Keep all code inside the .js file
- Generate javascript code with javascript code
- Repeat the same javascript element with only a number changing with each element
- Try to shorten the amount of code by doing this.
- Still be able to use any of the assigned variables alone somewhere like in a buy function.

I hope i gave all relevant information :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a Javascript array and a loop. That is, don't have separate variables UpgradePrice1, UpgradePrice2, etc., have one array called UpgradePrice.

Comment: Would do better learning how to write loops and functions so you don't have to repeat your code over and over.

Comment: Why not create a function that takes in two parameters? That looks to be the only thing changed between each if check.

Comment: How values of `UpgradePrice1` and `Upgrade2` are set ?

Comment: I have file named StandardValues.js where i assign variables the price, name and other stuff.
So i can use the variables other places without having to rewrite the price / name :)

Comment: Just updated the question with the same information :)

Comment: Regarding the update: you should be using an array of objects to hold all those values, not a bunch of separate variables.

Comment: Sounds interesting :) But would i still be able to use these variables elsewhere? for example if i need to buy the upgrade and have to do this: CREDITS = CREDITS - UpgradePrice1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method (in `index` you are passing the number in the end of your variables):

```
function myFunction(newUpgradePrice, newUpgrade, index) {
    if (CREDITS >= newUpgradePrice && newUpgrade === 0){
        document.getElementById("Upgrade" + index).style.display = "block";}
    else{document.getElementById("Upgrade" + index).style.display = "none";
 }
```

Is This what you are looking for? Anything needing to be changed to meet your needs?

Comment: (Take a look at the new code update)
How would i accomplish this when i still need to use UpgradePrice1 somewhere else than i this repeated code? :)
Sry for dumb questions quite new a Javascript :)

Comment: It's okay to hate me right now :P

Where and how do i assign newUpgradePrice, newUpgrade and index? :)

Comment: you pass them to the function when you call it. Funtions are used to reduce code. 
If you need to pass UpgradePrice4 and Upgrade4 to the function you call it like this:   myFunction(UpgradePrice4, Upgrade4, 4);

Comment: If you could make a final code with comments i can read and study for later use i would love you till the moon and back! :)
Im totaly new at JS and just wanna learn :)

Comment: The Code is very basic and self-explaining. But later today i'll make a complete example implementing it. At the moment i'm not near computer, i'm on my phone.

Comment: Basically, to implement the function above, just creat an array with your variables, additionally you can turn them into objects and stick them into the array, the call the function inside a for loop if you want to work them all at once.

Comment: If you're not comfortable with arrays I will suggest you to learn a bit more about these first, do as many exercises as you can till you full understand them, without that you will not understand my idea. And never quit at the first difficulty, insist, try to find solutions, think them, write them down with clear structure and explanatory flowchart/text/drawing, then you can "almost write" your code with comment lines with a resume of what goes where. This still helps me a lot and I'm still getting better at that. :)